# custome user creation in django fields not storing value

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to make a user registration form in django.
I browsed through many links but I am still confused. I am making some sill mistake please point it out.
here is my code:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):

    mobile = models.CharField(max_length = 20, null=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)


def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class CustomerRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    mobile = forms.CharField(max_length = 20)
    address = forms.CharField(max_length = 200)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','email','mobile','address','password1','password2')
```

**view.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from neededform.forms import CustomerRegistrationForm

def register(request):
    print "I am in register function"   

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = CustomerRegistrationForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                f = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/registered/')
    else:
        args = {}
        args.update(csrf(request))
        args['form'] = CustomerRegistrationForm()
    return render_to_response('User_Registration.html', args ,context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

what I am thinking is that when I do a `form.save()` in views.py, django should create the user in `auth_user` table and must insert the values (i.e **mobile** and **address** ) in the `UserProfile` table also. 

but what happening is that it is inserting data in `auth_user` table correctly but in the UserProfile table only `id` and `user_id` coloumns are filled, `mobile` and `address` both remains empty.

What am I doing wrong ? What else must be done ?
Thank you.

Comment: Your form is incorrect. You have added two fields to a form which is connected to the `User` model. So it saves all the fields for `User` and ignores the others. Manually add a `UserProfile` instance with your form's `cleaned_data` during `save`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the following:

```
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

You create a `UserProfile` object which *only* has its `user` attribute set!

I don't think that using `signal` is the best approach to your problem since it's not easy to pass the `mobile` and `address` from your form to the Profile creation point. Instead you can override the `save()` method of your `CustomerRegistrationForm` where you'd first save the user and then create the profile. Something like this:

```
class CustomerRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    # rest code ommited
    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(CustomerRegistrationForm, self).save()
        p = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user )
        p[0].mobile = self.cleaned_data['mobile']
        p[0].address = self.cleaned_data['address']
        p[0].save()
        return user
```

Comment: Thanks mate. That was a great help.